# Passing Data through One controller to Another using AngularJS $Watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I Create Two Seperate files for two controller one is Parent second one is child i want to pass data to one controller to another controller using .I search all google and i doesn't find any example for passing data through watch

Like This is My First controller

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.userData = [
            { fname: 'Physics', lname: 'dfg', adress: 'hggdhdf' },
            { fname: 'Chemistry', lname: 'fghdf', adress: 'dhfgfgh' },
            { fname: 'Math', lname: 'fghfgh', adress: 'fhgdfhg' }
        ];


        $scope.getData = function (user) {
            $scope.userData = angular.copy(user);
        };
        $scope.$watch('userData', function (newValue, oldValue, value) {
            console.log("DATA" + value);

        });
    }])
    .service('')
    .directive('myParent', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Parent.html',
        };
    })
```

This is a my Second Controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.$watch('userData', function (newValue,oldValue) {
                if(newValue!= oldValue){
                    $scope.userData = value;
                    console.log("u" + newValue);
                }
            });
 
}])
.directive('myChild', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'Child.html',
  };
});
```

But i doesn't know how to add services and factory can you please help

Comment: Add some additional code example, but usually the best way to share data between controller is to use services or factories. Or pass them by using bindings.

Comment: Yeah! i edit question can you see how i implement service in it